# How can I optimize the following code faster?

Tags: c#, loops, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two list:

`reports` count 6000 and
`invoices` count 6000

I have loop like this:

```
foreach (var item in reports) 
{
    item.SettlementProcessStatus =
        invoices.Any(t => t.InvoiceId == item.RelatedInvoiceId) 
           ? SettlementProcessStatus.Done 
           : SettlementProcessStatus.Error;
}
```

At first, this code has a good speed, but the higher the index, the slower it becomes.
what solutions are recommended to optimize it?

Comment: Think using a map with key InvoiceId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance problem is that your code has to iterate at least partially through `invoices` for each of your reports. To avoid this, first create a `HashSet` with all your invoice ID's and then search in there instead of your list.

Assuming you have integer ID's you could do:

```
var invoiceIds = new HasSet<int>(invoices.Select(x => x.InvoiceId));

foreach (var item in reports) 
    item.SettlementProcessStatus = invoiceIds.Contains(item.RelatedInvoiceId) ?
        SettlementProcessStatus.Done :
        SettlementProcessStatus.Error;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list for invoices, use a **dictionary** that have the RelatedInvoiceId as its Key Value.

That avoids iterating trough all list items each item.